# Assign value from dropdown to a variable in Razor pages in view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to get the value from a dropdown field and store it as a variable in the same View?

I have this dropdown

```cs
   <label for="vehicleMake">Choose your car's make:</label>

   <select id="vehicleMake" name="VehicleMake">
       @foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
       {
           if (@item.Category == 1072)
           {
               <option value="@item.UniqueId">@item.Description</option>

           }
       }
   </select>
```

and I would like to get the value from the select to store as a variable to use in the next dropdown something like this:

```cs
@{ var selectedVehicleMake = @*????? get the value from the previous dropdown ?????*@
}

    <label for="vehicleModel">Choose your car's model:</label> 
    <select id="vehicleModel" name="VehicleModel">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
        {
            if (@item.Category == 1073 && @item.VehicleMakeId == selectedVehicleMake)
            {
                <option value="@item.UniqueId">@item.Description</option>

            }
        }
     </select>
```

Or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor code is compiled on the server, so all variables are set before it's delivered to the browser. The Razor code doesn't know what value will be selected in the first dropdown to populate the second one.

What you would need to do is use a Javascript `onchange` event to perform an AJAX call and retrieve the data you need based on the first dropdown, to populate the second dropdown.

Comment: Thank you! You got me going in the right direction. I ended up doing this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384961/dropdown-from-jsonresult-returns-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384961/dropdown-from-jsonresult-returns-undefined)